# play json for nested json processing

Tags: json, scala, playframework

We have a json like the below

```
{
    "-KULpL4Qrzt4z8Go": {
        "dateTime": 1476778076353,
        "partyName": "AMBA",
        "partyId": "A101",
        "points": { 
            "-KULr3tag86GlJSZp": {
                "lat": 71.1426377,
                "lon": 29.0803357,
                "dtime": 1476778091998
            },
            "-KULr3v9zJA4NqLOf": {
                "lat": 91.1426377,
                "lon": 26.0803357,
                "dtime": 
            }
        } 
    }
  }
```

I use play json (for Scala 2.10.6) and want to get the data into the models

```
case class JsonPlay(dateTime:String,partyName:String,partyId:String) 
case class PointsPlay(lat:Double, lon:Double, dtime:Option[BigInt])
```

But my first Read itself throws and exception, saying unable to find \ dateTime etc.

```
implicit val baseReads: Reads[JsonPlay] = (
          (JsPath \ "dateTime").read[String] and
          (JsPath \ "partyName").read[String] and
          (JsPath \ "partyId").read[String] and
    )(JsonPlay.apply _)
```

Appreciate any pointers/help in getting this work. Thanks.

-Venkiram

Answer (score 1):

`dateTime` is a long in this case. It should be:

```
case class JsonPlay(dateTime: Long, partyName: String, partyId: String) 

 implicit val baseReads: Reads[JsonPlay] = (
          (JsPath \ "dateTime").read[Long] and
          (JsPath \ "partyName").read[String] and
          (JsPath \ "partyId").read[String] and
    )(JsonPlay.apply _)
```